# My jupyter notebook continues to run [*], but will not output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Using this same code I was able to return a list of the frequencies of letters within .txt files. On one of my runs of the code, jupyter notebook suddenly would not run the code. I've looked around the web for solutions, none of which have worked.

Here is the code:

```
def most_frequent(string:str):
    """
    Takes a string and returns the letters in decreasing order of frequency
    """
    string = string.lower()
    for i in string:
        lst = [char for char in string]
    
    just_letters = ''
    for char in lst:
        if((ord(char) >= ord('a') and ord(char) <= ord('z'))):
            just_letters += char
           
    letter_freq = []
    for i in just_letters:
        letter_freq.append(just_letters.count(i))
        
    return sorted(list(set(zip(letter_freq, just_letters))), reverse = True)
    
def frequency_in_file(file: str):
    """
    Returns the frequency of letters in decreasing order of a given file path.
    *Note*: Remember to insert an r before the apostrophized file path
    
    file: file path as a string
    """
    return most_frequent(open(file).read())

frequency_in_file(r"words.txt")
```

I usually would find an output somewhat like this, of course depending on the file:

```
([3, 'a']
 [2, 's']
 [2, 't'])
```

When I interrupt the kernel, the traceback ends at:

```
def most_frequent(string:str)
    string = string.lower()
        for i in string:
            lst = [char for char in string]    #specifically this line
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the notebook or even restarting the notebook server process altogether?

Comment: I will suggest you to restart the kernel and try re-running the code.

Comment: Yes I have definitely restarted the kernel, I've restarted notebook/anaconda, I've restarted my computer, all to no avail.

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to process?  That is an *amazingly* inefficient loop (you are recalculating `lst` as many times as there are characters in the file, producing exactly the same value each time), if the file is huge you may just not be waiting long enough for it to finish.

Comment: @jasonharper actually I think that's what it totally is. *facepalm* it worked for the smaller tests I was performing, but eventually didn't scale up. Do you have any suggestions for fixes?

Comment: Just get rid of that first loop completely.  You don't actually need `lst` at all - you could just as easily do `for char in string:` in the second loop, rather than `for char in lst:`.

Comment: @jasonharper that actually has made it efficient enough for me to get the results I needed. Thanks!